# insert text in a file using echo command

Tags: linux, sudo, echo

I am trying to insert some text in a file in the following way

```
sudo echo "abc-abc/abc/abc" >> /etc/portage/make.conf
```

but it give me the error
Permission denied

although I am using sudo command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo just executes the first command, in your case " echo "abc-abc/abc/abc" ".

So the rest of the command (writing in /etc/portage/make.conf) will be executed in user mode.

You just have to modify the permissions on the file using chmod.

Comment: Let's be serious, you don't want to `chmod` a file to modify it when you have `sudo` access.

Answer (score 3):

In that command line, your shell opens the `/etc/portage/make.conf` in append mode, makes it the stdout of a new process and runs `sudo` in that new process. It's not `sudo` nor `echo` that open the file, it's your  shell which is running with your credentials.

You'd need the file to be opened by the command started as root. So it could be:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "abc-abc/abc/abc" >> /etc/portage/make.conf'
```

Or:

```
echo "abc-abc/abc/abc" | sudo tee -a /etc/portage/make.conf > /dev/null
```